# Recommendations for an address book/directory plugin Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, directory

I'd like to clarify a few bits first:

- I don't want to display a directory, just the search input form
- I want each result to display on each line.
- It will show things like name, email, twitter id etc...
- I'd like to include star rating if possible.
- It must not require a click through to reach a post with full details

Essentially I'm after a plugin to maintain a simple database, with star rating and return results by row, similar to a simple PHP mysql lookup and print.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 free plugins from the wordpress directory

http://wordpress.org/plugins/connections/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/business-directory-plugin/

Alternatively, Try looking at the solutions these plugins offer (Paid, but not that much and premium plugins often worth it!)

http://codecanyon.net/browse/tags/default/business%20listings

Comment: Thanks Raphael. I have checked out these two. Possibly connections will do what I need, but I don't think the bus directory plugin will.

Comment: @user1721451 Keep us posted!